# Python Selenium: How to input some text in search form if its iFrame?

Tags: python, selenium

Python Selenium: How to input some text in search form if its iFrame? 
I tried some methods, but it did not work.

```
search_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.search-text')
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(search_input).send_keys('indicator').perform()
```

and

```
search_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.search-text')
search_input = driver.send_keys('indicator')
```

switch to frame

```
frame = waitLoading('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/iframe');
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```

and I use

```
def waitLoading(LOADING_ELEMENT_XPATH):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5000).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.blockOverlay')))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5000).until(EC.staleness_of(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.blockOverlay')))
    return driver.find_element_by_xpath(LOADING_ELEMENT_XPATH)
```

following error is

```
      File "test_search.py", line 53, in <module>
    search_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/input')
  File "/Users/annuitcoeptis/Documents/work/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/Users/annuitcoeptis/Documents/work/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/Users/annuitcoeptis/Documents/work/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/annuitcoeptis/Documents/work/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/input"}
```

Comment: Did you switch to that iframe?

Comment: yes. I switch to frame

Comment: Show us how did you switch to iframe ? Your HTML code or link to website would be useful.

Comment: Ok. Can you share the HTML code also ?

Comment: Ok. I'll edit 1st post

Comment: 1. Do you know that `WebDriverWait(driver, 5000)` means *wait for about 1,5 hours*? 2. If you want to wait until element no more present in DOM, use `WebDriverWait(driver, 5000).until_not(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.blockOverlay')))` instead of `WebDriverWait(driver, 5000).until(EC.staleness_of(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.blockOverlay')))`

Comment: *"...but it did not work..."*. Can you share little more details/

Comment: I understood. But it immediately works, when xpath located. But I edited my code with your method. Its more laconically :)

Comment: whitch details? I will share.

Comment: Try to wait `WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.search-text'))).send_keys('indicator')` or check whether there is another iframe (it's OK situation if one iframe contain another iframe - you should switch to all embeded frames one by one)

Comment: use @ with the person name , so that they will get notified.

Comment: Post the relevant HTML of the IFRAME and desired elements inside. My guess is that you are switching into the wrong IFRAME, not waiting for the elements to appear, or have a bad locator for the element.

Answer (score 1):

```
**First you need to switch your driver on iframe**
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))


## Insert text via xpath ##
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/input")
elem.send_keys("Text Enter")
```

Comment: I alredy did it